# Qlikview Source Column labels with [x]

Tags: string, qlikview, brackets, square

I have a Dashboard that allows users to plot values of two channels against each other.  Some of the data channels are straight string values, like TEMP_F, others are arrays,  PLOT[0], PLOT[1], PLOT[2].  When I select any channel without the [x] I get data plotted. When the channel name contains the [x], I get and error "no data to display" in the chart.

I understand that the square brackets are in equations when a field has a space, like average([TEMP F]).  I suspect this may be related.  Is there a way to get Qlik to interpret the channel names as strings.

Does anybody have a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the column name in ""

```
sum("PLOT[0]")
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a column name like `TEMP F`, with space in it, use parentheses around the column name. In your case:

```
sum("PLOT[0]")
```